# Do we need to authenticate user in websocket connection if the user is already authenticated by login page or auth0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to web sockets implementation, currently I have react with node js app. If the user signs up and logins user will be redirected to home page. I'm trying to integrate my app with socket io for notification and small user chat purpose. My doubt is, do i need to authenticate the user in web socket connection also? Because the user is already landed in my page by logging in. Is it necessary ?

Comment: By logging in I assume the user gets a session? You need to associate their socket with the session (i.e. store the socket in the session)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send the token that you get from Auth0 when initializing the socket client. Then in the BE, you need to check that token.

[SocketIo docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/middlewares/#Sending-credentials)

Comment: If your answer is just a copy-paste of the docs, there's no need to post it here. Just post a comment with a [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#Sending-credentials) instead. The reason for this is that the docs might change, so you're providing a potentially obsolete version for future readers.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, I'm new here. Edited my answer.

Comment: No problem :) However I don't think this is what OP is asking anyway. They aren't asking how to auth in socket.io, they're asking whether they need to do it in the first place. If they keep the user's socket in the server's session, I don't think they have to auth the socket connection separately. Afaik socket.io auth is for situations in which all server-client traffic runs through the socket.

Comment: That makes it an interesting question. If you want to restrict socket access for logged in users, how would you do it if you have JWT-based authentication for your REST API? At least in my web app, JWT verification happens in middleware in Express, so sockets would remain open. This is why I added socket authentication as well.

Not sure how this works in .NET or Spring, though, so perhaps this warrants a better answer.

Comment: I guess if the Login page is protected and you have CORS, then WS connection should not be possible from the login page. But if you have an unprotected route on the same domain, what would stop the user from running some socket io code from the console and listening in?